# NIFI PutHiveQL HiveAccessControlException Permission denied: user [anonymous] does not have [SELECT] privilege

Tags: hive, hiveql, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-nifi

I supply an insert sql to PutHiveQL and get this error:

HiveAccessControlException Permission denied: user [anonymous] does not have [SELECT] privilege

When we install the nifi in HDF, and access it from the browser through http://localhost:6434/nifi/... is the default user "anonymous"? is it the reason why i'm getting the error? may i know where should I configure the permission in hive?

Answer (score 0):

Is NiFi/HDF running on a Hadoop node? If so, what user is it running under? You'll need to grant SELECT permissions for that user:

https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.0/bk_Ranger_User_Guide/content/user_access_hive_db_tables_cmd_line.html

If that user does not exist in Hadoop, you will have to add it:

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html

or run NiFi/HDF as a user that does exist on the OS and Hadoop.

If NiFi/HDF is not running on a Hadoop node, you'll need to add the user/group (with the same UID/GID) that is running NiFi to Hadoop (using the above link for guidance), or create a user/group on the HDF node that is already in Hadoop (and has SELECT privileges for the table).

Comment: NiFi is running on a datanode.  User 'root' runs the NiFi service.  My question is why the error says 'anonymous' user?  So does this mean that we just need to grant select to user 'root'? not 'anonymous'? But i created the table in hive UI from ambari logged in as admin.  In /app/hive/warehouse, the table folder is owned by 'hive', group 'hdfs'

Comment: What are the credentials you are providing to the HiveConnectionPool? If none, then you are anonymous and will have to grant privileges to the anonymous user.

Comment: nothing... but when i use 'hive' as username, i still get the same error, this time instead of 'anonymous', it says 'hive'.

Comment: Does the hive user have select privileges for that table? You may have to use Beeline or Ambari to do a GRANT SELECT (see the first link above)

Comment: i run this query, still got error:

grant select on table default.tablename to user hive;

Comment: the whole error is
HiveAccessControlException Permission denied: user [hive] does not have [SELECT] privilege on [default/values__tmp__table__560/tmp_values_col1,tmp_values_col2,tmp_values_col3,tmp_values_col4,tmp_values_col5,tmp_values_col6]

Comment: You'll have to run that command as a user that has the privileges to grant permissions. Or you can use that account for your Hive connection. The Hive documentation should have information on how to set up admin users and such.

Comment: i logged in as admin in ambari. I didn't get any error after running the grant in hive ui so i thought it was granting it.  actually, my nifi is in one hadoop node, but my HiveConnectionPool is connecting to another node.